# swap list characters and get rid of comma in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

How can I take a nested list swap the names, get rid of the comma in the nested list

Have

```
lst = [['Mart, Wal'], ['Store, Toy']]
```

Want

```
newlst = [['Wal Mart'], ['Toy Store']]
```

Comment: code in separate blocks

Comment: Are you sure that this is the format your data is in?  In your question, the inner lists contain a single string that contains a comma, instead of containing two strings.

Answer (score 0):

You want to go through each sublist of the main list, then in the content of each sublist you get the string, remove the comma and space using `split()` and reverse the order of the elements returned by the splitting.

Bonus point: if this is your homework, a one-liner solution will raise suspicions.

```
lst = [['Mart, Wal'], ['Store, Toy']]
newlst = [[f"{s[1]} {s[0]}"] for s in sublist[0].split(", ") for sublist in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple recursive function, which will reverse the list.

```
lst = [['Mart, Wal, Store, Hodgins'], ['Store, Toy']]

def reverse(l, reversed_l):
    reversed_l.append(l[-1])
    if len(l) > 1:
        reverse(l[:-1], reversed_l)
    return reversed_l


output = []
for item in lst:
    reversed_l = reverse(item[0].split(", "), [])
    output.append([" ".join(reversed_l)])

print(output)
```

> (python3) ➜  Desktop python stack-s3.py
>
> [['Hodgins Store Wal Mart'],['Toy Store']]